# How to fix a problem with Super PuTTY not opening multiple Telnet nodes in separate tabs when I attempt group select console to nodes

Tags: emulation, telnet, qemu

When I group select to console into multiple Eve-NG Telnet nodes within a lab and then select ">_Console To Selected Nodes", Super Putty opens, however, it will only open a tab for a single Telnet node.

I have created a lab in Eve-NG with two vSRX Telnet nodes that are connected via ge-0/0/1 and ge-0/0/2.  This lab also has an Eve-NG cloud image where the vSRX nodes are connected to it via ge-0/0/3. I added two GUI enabled Linux VNC hosts which are also connected to the afore mentioned cloud image and each via e0.

I set up Super PuTTY in the Windows 11 registry and then set it as the default Telnet application with the "only allow single instance" mode enabled.

Ideally, Super PuTTY should open both vSRX nodes within a single instance and each within a separate tab.

I discovered through troubleshooting that if a Super PuTTY session is already opened on the desktop, then both vSRX's will be opened in separate tabs.  Or if the "only allow single instance" mode is disabled in Super Putty, then the vSRX's are both opened but in separate Super PuTTY instances.  This behavior is not desirable.

Would anyone be able to offer any tips that I could try at solving the above issue?